# Force Android system ui to hide

Tags: android

I'm having trouble with Android's immersive sticky layout.

Under some circumstances, usual transparent status bar with home, back and multitask buttons becomes non-transparent visible, and even if I set right visibility flags back on, the non-transparent bar stays on screen.

Is there some programming way to force system UI to hide, and preferably to become transparent again?

Comment: Exactly which circumstances? User can swipe up the system bar every time, in every app. If they are showing when your app is restored from background, re-apply your immersive flags from `onResume`.

Comment: I have a WebView in my app, and everytime it loads a new page buttons reappear, and do not hide by themselves. Also when software keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method to hide the system UI in my app:

```
 protected void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```